# Additive functor is exact $\iff$ quasi-isomorphisms preserved?

Tags: reference-request, category-theory, homological-algebra

While reading Weibel's Homological Algebra, on pg. 391 he considers an additive functor $F:\mathcal{A}\to\mathcal{B}$ between abelian categories, and writes "If $F$ is not exact, then the induced functor $\mathbb{K}(\mathcal{A})\to\mathbb{K}(\mathcal{B})$ will not preserve quasi-isomorphisms."

I did some digging, and based on this [MO post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/108670/additive-functors-preserving-quasi-isomorphism), I assume it is true that

> if $F:\mathcal{A}\to\mathcal{B}$ is additive between abelian categories, the induced functor $\mathbb{K}(\mathcal{A})\to\mathbb{K}(\mathcal{B})$ on the homotopy categories will preserve quasi-isomorphisms if and only if $F$ is exact.

It seems mentioned in passing in a lot of sources, but not proven anywhere. Does anyone have a proof of this proposition or reference to a place where it is? (If it's indeed true, that is.)

Comment: See Lemma 2 of [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4486908/394668).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

$\Leftarrow$: if $F$ is exact, then it commutes with taking homology; in particular, it preserves acyclic complexes. Now use the fact that a map is a quasi-isomorphism iff its mapping cone is acyclic and that any functor on chain complexes induced from a functor between abelian categories preserves mapping cones.

$\Rightarrow$: we'll prove the contrapositive. Suppose $0 \to a \to b \to c \to 0$ is a short exact sequence not preserved by $F$, so $F(a) \to F(b) \to F(c)$ is not exact. Now, a three-term complex is exact iff it's acyclic iff it's quasi-isomorphic to $0$, so $F$ does not preserve quasi-isomorphisms.

Comment: Why are you distinguishing between 'acylic' and 'exact'? I'm pretty sure Weibel writes they are the same thing. I also don't understand the bit about three-term complexes - what's so special about them? Also, what role did the additivity of $F$ play here?

Comment: @Exterior: I'm not distinguishing between them except insofar as they're different words; you can see that I write that they're equivalent. (There's also a slight difference in emphasis but that's not particularly important here.) An additive functor is exact iff it preserves short exact sequences. Additivity is necessary to induce a functor on the homotopy categories of chain complexes (you need the functor to send zero to zero and to send chain homotopies to chain homotopies).

Comment: @QiaochuYuan is it correct that the same proof shows a pointed functor between abelian categories preserves q.i's iff it is exact? I think preserving zero objects suffices to lift to a functor between chain complexes..

Comment: @Exterior: it doesn't suffice for the fact I use above that an additive functor induces a functor on chain complexes which preserves taking mapping cones. And, again, what we want (at least) is a functor on the *homotopy category* of chain complexes, and that requires respecting chain homotopies. The category of chain complexes as a bare category is beside the point. I don't know why you're so set on dropping additivity; it really is crucial for working with chain complexes.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan I'm not set on it at all, I'm just trying to realize how crucial it is :)
I'm not familiar with mapping cones. Could you explain exactly where additivity is needed there? I understand that the big picture wants functors between the homotopy categories, I'm just trying to understand whether additivity is needed for the equivalence between exactness and preserving q.i's.

Comment: @Exterior: see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mapping_cone_(homological_algebra). Additivity is needed to ensure compatibility with direct sums. For a functor between abelian categories these conditions are actually equivalent; see https://qchu.wordpress.com/2012/09/14/a-meditation-on-semiadditive-categories/ for a lengthy discussion. If you have more questions it would probably be best to ask them separately.